# How do you return an Observable of type Observable<A> which contains/relies-on an Observable of type Observable<B> ?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-http-interceptors

I am writing some code inside an `HttpInterceptor` function. The function, `intercept` is supposed to return an Observable with type `HttpEvent<any>`.

The tricky part for me is that I need to make an asynchronous call inside this function, and I can only return that `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>` once I am inside the "success" function of my asynchronous code.

So my question is, how do I return an Observable of the correct type that really contains another Observable of a different type?

Here is my code

```
@Injectable()
export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private valueService: ValueService){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const duplicate = req.clone({
            params: req.params.set('newVal', this.valueService.getNewValue())  // this.valueService.getNewValue() returns an Observable<string> !!
        });

        return next.handle(duplicate);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `flatMap`. Check this link: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.valueService.getNewValue().
      switchMap((data:string)=>{  //or flatMap
         //You get "data"
         const duplicate = req.clone({
         params: req.params.set('newVal', data);
         return next.handle(duplicate);
       });
}
```

Comment: So Typescript understands that the return type of the thing that is ultimately returned matches the return type of the function? How does that work exactly?

Comment: You received a req, you must return a next.hanlde(req). But you create an Observable, and with switchMap, not return the observable, you create a new request using data from the observable and return next.hadle of the new request